# Would US president Theodore Roosevelt refer to his political enemies as "vermin"?

Tags: united-states, history, politics, quotes

A [publication](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Information_Bulletin/IgmcE5fRR68C?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=vermin) of the Library of Congress says:

> Mr. Foulke in his letters reveals an unusual frankness in letting President Roosevelt know of the attitudes of his political enemies -- **"small vermin," as the President called them**.

Are there any documented examples of the President saying or writing "vermin" to characterize his political enemies?

Comment: More of a History stack question than Skeptics, I would think.

Comment: @jeffronicus Skeptics is supposed to be for investigating unreferenced claims.  The Library of Congress is making this claim without any references.

Comment: Before it became popular to do this for real in some places in Europe, US political discourse used to have those [figurative] calls often enough, it seems https://www.theodorerooseveltcenter.org/Research/Digital-Library/Record?libID=o301664&from=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.theodorerooseveltcenter.org%2FSearch%3Fcp%3D1%26f%3DEverything%26pl%3D1%26r%3D1%26ro%3D1%26searchTerms%3DPanic%2520of%25201907

Comment: I'd have thought that "draining the swamp" was a more recent euphemism, but that also goes back more than a century https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drain_the_swamp Funnily enough the latter phrase was used by TR's contemporary Berger, whom you might know of.

Comment: And TR is associated with vermin elimination one more funny/practical way... http://www.teddyrooseveltterrier.org/ https://nypost.com/2017/03/23/these-fearless-pups-thirst-for-rat-blood/

Comment: @Fizz the cartoon you linked, the "vermin" are problems such as "abuses," "errors," "rebates," "unfair methods," and "bank looting".  The vermin are not people.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Google Books is too limited for me to get the full context, but this is what I have, evidently from a [letter he wrote in 1900](https://books.google.com/books?id=tcm3DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT74&dq=%22vermin%20like%20Jack%20Chapman%22%201900%20letter&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiLuKL29siCAxXwmIkEHUtvCVwQuwV6BAgJEAc#v=onepage&q=%22vermin%20like%20Jack%20Chapman%22%201900%20letter&f=false). From [The years of preparation, 1868-1900 - Page 1356](https://books.google.com/books?id=12N3AAAAMAAJ&q=Bryans%20success.%20i%20cannot%20express&dq=Bryans%20success.%20i%20cannot%20express&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjtxdaU9siCAxVqmIkEHZxgAuIQ6AF6BAgMEAM):

> …which will help us carry through our ticket this year, for I am incapable of feeling more earnestly about anything than I do about the awful misery and wrong, the shame and disgrace which would be caused by [Bryan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Jennings_Bryan)'s success. I cannot express the anger and contemptuous indignation with which I regard the cultivated men from [Schurz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Schurz) and [Godkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwin_Lawrence_Godkin) down to the **smaller vermin** like [Jack Chapman](http://johnjayhomestead.org/jay-family-stories-john-jay-chapman-1862-1933/) and [Erving Winslow](https://digital.janeaddams.ramapo.edu/items/show/2364) who at this great crisis show themselves traitors to their country.

(Links mine.)

Comment: He doesn't use the word "enemies", though?

Comment: @gerrit That's not in quotes in the original claim, so it's not Roosevelt's choice of words.